# 'IndexError: list index out of range'. What's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

```
response = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/?tab=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
product = random.choice(soup.find_all(class_='gamehover_GameTitle_mrkD1'))
print('Рассмотрите эту игру: ' + product.text)
```

I tried taking a different class. Then it returned an empty list in 'product'.

Answer (score 1):

When I checked it out, there were no elements with the class `gamehover_GameTitle_mrkD1` on the website. This results in `soup.find_all` returning an empty list. Because `random.choice` then doesn't have any items to choose from, it will raise an indexerror.

You can fix this error by choosing a class name that does actually exist on the web page. On the time I checked it, all game titles had  `animated_featured_capsule_Title_3vZJE` as class, but this can change over time. If your code with a correct classname stops working, you'd best check whether the class name is still correct, and if not, change it.